# What is the difference between Groovy Micronaut's @Client injected RxHttpClient vs RxHttpClient.create?

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I'm creating a Micronaut HTTP Client using the `@Client` annotation in Groovy, and the compiler complains if I use anything other than a static constant. However, this limits me from being able to change the URL per environment by passing in a config value.

So I tried using `RxHttpClient.create(myUrl)` in my service instead, and the same request I'm making returns a 403. The RxHttpClient docs say

> Create a new HttpClient. Note that this method should only be used 
>   outside of the context of an application. Within Micronaut use Inject to > inject a client instead.

This doesn't explain **why** I shouldn't use the `create` method, and I'm left with an inability to make requests to different servers on different environments. What is the difference between the two clients I'm creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Client` annotation will inject a managed client that has been dependency injected with additional instrumentation features for tracing, propagation etc. By using `create` Micronaut cannot dependency inject the instance so certain features of the framework won't work.

In addition with `create` you have to ensure you manually `close` the client since Micronaut cannot manage the life cycle and cleanly shutdown the client when the application shuts down.

Finally regarding using a static constant to `@Client`, it is not true that this limits you since the value can include placeholders. For example:

```
@Client("${my.server}")
```

Then in `application.yml` you can configure:

```
my:
  server: http://foo.com
```

Or even better you can use the new HTTP services feature. See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#serviceDiscoveryManual